# What are the rules of Parallelism?

Tags: style, parallelism, structure

What are the **rules of parallelism**? I've been reading a lot about it since yesterday and all I encounter is "*They must have the same grammatical form*"? What does this exactly mean?

I know how to make **parallel sentences** with gerunds. The things get trickier when it comes to using modifiers.

For example:

> I love using the phone that you bought me and the computer.

On the left side of the conjunction there is a noun phrase that consists of an article + noun + another modifier and on the right side there is an article + noun.

They are both noun phrases but the first one has additional modifier. Is that still considered a parallel sentence?

Another example:

> I like to swim and to feel good.

Here on the right side of the conjunction there is an infinitive and on the left side there is an infinitive + complement? Is that parallel?

Comment: Note that using parallel constructions is a matter of style. It is never required. In some cases it may make writing clearer or more elegant. Note also that parallelism need not be accomplished inside a single sentence. One can write two or more sentences which are parallel to each other.

Answer (score 2):

Parallelism  can get complicated, but basically, it's about the structure of a sentence  in writing. It means keeping the structure the same:

He **loved** playing cards and he **was** stupid. [not parallel]

He loved **playing cards** and **riding motorbikes**. [parallel]

He **was** stupid and he **was** also shy. [parallel]

**Earning a good living** in the modern world takes patience and **he finds** this difficult. [not parallel]

**Earning a good living** in the modern world takes patience so does **keeping an eye out for opportunity**. [parallel]

**Earning a good livin**g in the modern world takes patience so does **your job.** [not parallel].

**Earning a good living** in the modern world takes patience so does **doing your job**. [parallel].

Those are merely examples. I have not yet systematized it in my own mind.

Parallelism is not called for in literary writing, necessarily. It applies to other kinds of writing.

Comment: For example, in a noun phrase, If I have "article + adverb + adjective + noun", should the pattern of the last item be the same as the first one? "We had a really bad summer and a nice winter" Is that parallel?

Comment: @BoSsYyY  Yes, that is perfectly parallel. Not parallel would be, for example: We had a really bad summer and a bad winter is expected. [using an active verb and then a passive one]